# exc_bad_access on createfixture

Tags: c++, vector, box2d, cocos2d-x

I got a class called block. In this class I load a sprite, make a b2bodydef and a fixturedef.
In another class I make 2 blocks, add them to a vector and then loop the vector to create fixtures:

```
Block *b = new Block(5, 20);
this->addChild(b->sprite);
blocks.push_back(b);


Block *b1 = new Block(15, 35);
this->addChild(b1->sprite);
blocks.push_back(b1);

b2Body *blockbody;
for(int i = 0; i<blocks.size();i++)
{
    b2BodyDef def = blocks[i]->blockbodydef;
    blockbody = world->CreateBody(&def);
    if(blockbody == NULL)
        cocos2d::CCLog("blockbody is null");
    blockbody->CreateFixture(&blocks[i]->blockshapedef);
}
```

I get the error "exc_bad_access" on the last line.

This is my block.h:

```
class Block
{

public:
    cocos2d::CCSprite *sprite;
    Block(float x, float y);
    b2BodyDef blockbodydef;
    b2FixtureDef blockshapedef;
};
```

and .cpp:

```
Block::Block(float x, float y)
{
sprite = cocos2d::CCSprite::create("Block.png");
sprite->setPosition(ccp(x,y));

blockbodydef.type = b2_kinematicBody;
blockbodydef.position.Set(x/PTM_RATIO,y/PTM_RATIO);
blockbodydef.userData = sprite;


b2PolygonShape blockPoly;
blockPoly.SetAsBox(37.5/PTM_RATIO , 37.5 / PTM_RATIO);

blockshapedef.shape = &blockPoly;
blockshapedef.density = 2.0f;
blockshapedef.friction = 0.2f;
blockshapedef.restitution = 0.8f;
}
```

blockbody isn't null, neither is blockshapedef. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Removing `b2PolygonShape blockPoly;` from the .cpp and adding it to the .h file did the trick.